# Custom Serializer and ViewSet for ManyToManyField in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a M2M relationship between the `Entity` and `EntityGroup` and I want to save the corresponding entity index to the `EntityGroup` just like an entity array to database.

Since I used a custom through Model with additional field `index` inside, I need to serialize the `index` to the corresponding `entity` to the response, how should I implement that?

I'm new to django and django-rest-framework and it seems there are not similar M2M examples after a few google search. Here is my thought, a serializer could only serialize the only one model's fields with `ForeignKey` relationship, a viewset could have a custom model based on `queryset` which could merge the relationships for a few models. So I need to implement a more expandable viewset with a custom `queryset` inside?

Here is my code:

models.py

```py
class Entity(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField()
    name = models.CharField()

class EntityGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    entities = models.ManyToManyField(Entity,
        through='EntityGroupRelationship',
        through_fields=('group', 'entity'),
        related_name='groups'
    )

class EntityGroupRelationship(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(EntityGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    index = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

serializers.py

```py
class EntitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = '__all__'

class EntityGroupRelationshipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EntityGroupRelationship
        fields = '__all__'

class EntityGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entities = EntitySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = EntityGroup
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```py
class EntityGroupViewSet(BaseModelViewSet):
    queryset = EntityGroup.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntityGroupSerializer

class EntityGroupRelationshipViewSet(BaseModelViewSet):
    queryset = EntityGroupRelationship.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntityGroupRelationshipSerializer
```

Current response

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "entities": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "",
        }]
    },
    ...
]
```

Expected respponse

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "entities": [
            {
                "index": 1,
                "info": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "",
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using incorrect serializer for that. Use `EntityGroupRelationshipSerializer` instead of `EntitySerializer`. Also you need to pass correct `fields`

```
class EntitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = '__all__'

class EntityGroupRelationshipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entity = EntitySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = EntityGroupRelationship
        fields = ('index', 'entity')

class EntityGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entities = EntityGroupRelationshipSerializer(many=True) # here should be EntityGroupRelationshipSerializer

    class Meta:
        model = EntityGroup
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Thanks Sardorbek! `EntityGroupRelationshipSerializer` is my expected one, but your `entities = EntityGroupRelationshipSerializer(many=True)` in `EntityGroupSerializer` makes me confused a lot, the `Entity` hasn't an `index` fields to serialize, (django reports that error in my a few tries,) so is that line a mistake?

Comment: @Itachi didn't get your question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Forget that, problem resolved, my bad. :)

Comment: @Itachi great))